# WMI: Win32_Process.create(): Program files (x86) gives "Path Not Found"

Tags: vbscript, process, wmi

Could someone please share any ideas why this code gives a "Path Not Found" error? Thank you.

```
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set Win32ProcessStartup = WMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set Win32ProcessStartupConfig = Win32ProcessStartup.SpawnInstance_
Win32ProcessStartupConfig.ShowWindow = 2

Set Win32Process = WMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
returnValue = Win32Process.Create ("iexplore.exe", _
                                   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer", _
                                   Win32ProcessStartupConfig, processIDOutputValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't specify the full path to iexplorer.exe in the first (command line) parameter. The second one (current dir) sets the current folder for the child process, but doesn't help the parent to find the .exe.

Comment: Yep that was the reason alright. Thank you very much! :cD